# Trying to get property of non-object. Error in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm kinda new at laravel and need your help.

I have this IR model :

```
class IR extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable=['irnum','date','subject','cause','facts','as','at','rec','user_id'];
    protected $casts=['user_id'=>'int'];
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(user::class);
    }
    public static $rules =array (
        'date'=>'required',
        'status'=>'required|min:10',
        'cause' => 'required|min:10',
        'facts' => 'required|min:10',
        'ir-as' => 'required|min:10',
        'rec' => 'required|min:10',
        'ir-at' => 'required|min:10',
    );
}
```

and route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
 Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
 })->middleware('guest');
 Route::resource('tasks','TaskController');
 Route::get('ir',function ()
  {
        return View::make('tasks/ir');
  });
    Route::resource('irs','IRController');
 Route::auth();
});
```

and this is my controller :

```
class IRController extends Controller
{
/**
 * The task repository instance.
 *
 * @var TaskRepository
 */
 protected $irs;
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @param  TaskRepository  $tasks
 * @return void
 */
 public function __construct(IRRepository $irs)
 {
     $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->irs = $irs;
 }
/**
 * Display a list of all of the user's task.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return Response
 */

    public function index(Request $request)
 {
     return view('tasks.ir',[
          'irs' => $this->irs->forUser($request->user()),
      ]);
 }
/**
 * Create a new task.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return Response
 */

 public function create()
  {
     return View::make('irs.create');
 }  
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $request->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
     $input =$request->all();
     $validation=Validator::make($input, IR::$rules);
     if($validation->passes())
      {

          IR::create($input);
          return Redirect::route('tasks.ir');
     }
        return Redirect::route('tasks.ir')
           ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation)
         ->with('message','There were validation errors.');

 }
/**
 * Destroy the given task.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @param  Task  $task
 * @return Response
 */
  public function destroy(Request $request, IR $irs)
  {

  }
}
```

I really dont know what causes to throw this error. 
Error throws when i add Incident report.
Pls help.
New at laravel

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you're getting an error?

Comment: When I'm trying to add an incident report. or IR.

Comment: Make sure there is logged in user when you call `$request->user_id=Auth::user()->id;`

Comment: there is a logged in user. it is shown in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saying you get an error when you're trying to add an incident report or IR, so I assume problem is in a `store()` action.

I can see only one potential candidate for this error in a `store()` action:

```
Auth::user()->id;
```

Add `dd(Auth::user());` before this clause and if it will output `null`, use `check()` method, which checks if any user is authenticated:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    Auth::user->id;
}
```

Comment: It throws MethodNotAllowedHttpException when i tried to add data. I dont know why the error changed.

Comment: You got MethodNotAllowedHttpException, because now your code is working and it tries to redirect to `tasks.ir` route which doesn't exist. You can see all defined routes with `php artisan route:list`

Comment: tasks.ir exist. its in resources/views/tasks/ir.blade.php

Comment: @RichardMisterio, `tasks/ir.blade.php` is a view, not route.

Comment: so what should i do? @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: You need to create correct route or change your current code. The thing is that's different problem, so you should accept an answer (I guess it solves your original problem) and then you should start new question and describe there what exactly you want to achieve, post appropriate code etc.